# Python regular expression for matching 3 and 16 characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to regular expressions and I'm trying to produce in Python the following condition.

String between **3 and 16 characters** long and being **alpha-numeric** or containing a hyphen (but **not as the first or last character**).

This is what I have so far:

```
 rule = re.compile(r'(^{0,16})')

    if rule.search(value):
        msg = u"Does not validate"
        raise ValidationError(msg)
```

Comment: you are looking for the beginning of the line, 0-16 times in a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `format` to shorten it:

```
'{0}({0}|-){1}{0}'.format('[a-zA-Z0-9]','{1-14}')
```

@poke's version is better if the requirement for case-insensitivity is inherent to the whole query.

Comment: Machines making machines. How perverse!

Answer (score 6):

```
re.compile('[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9-]{1,14}[A-Z0-9]', re.I)
```

This will accept alpha-numeric character at the beginning and at the end, and require 1 too 14 alpha-numeric or hypen characters in between.

Comment: @User7 - Note that a hyphen *must* be the last character in the `[]` expression in order to match itself.